# Readings of 漏斗：じょうご vs ろうと

Tags: readings, word-choice

Is there any difference in meaning between the words じょうご and ろうと, both meaning something like "funnel", both written with the kanji 漏斗?

There's some indication in the answers [here](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/40533.html) that ろうと may be a specific term used when you're talking about scientific experiments, but no such distinction in the dictionaries I have access to.

How about in compounds? For example, 漏斗雲{ろうとうん} - is it always ろうと in these cases?

Comment: そういえば化学の授業では「ろうと」って言ってました。でも家では「じょうご」って言ってたと思います。ここのほうが詳しいかもしれません・・・ http://www.geocities.co.jp/SilkRoad-Oasis/8051/new/funnel.htm または　http://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%BC%8F%E6%96%97

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In typical everyday usage, the two words are fundamentally the same. However, distinctions can be made between them.

- zyougo: from 上戸 (a person who enjoys liquor), it expresses how liquids are sucked in without spilling like a funnel. The meaning is more abstract and includes funnel-like objects as well.
- routo: (non-abstract) specifically a funnel; this is the preferred terminology in science experiments.

> How about in compounds?

I would expect it to be routo-. From the above explanation, zyougo is merely atezi for 上戸, so this limits the likely hood of compounds with the same reading. Also, compounds typically narrow a meaning to something more specific, while zyougo is already an abstract noun compared to the more specific routo.